# How do I change the photo editor on stencyl?

Tags: stencyl

Hi I am using a mac right now and the stencyl website tells me to go to file then preferences except I don't see preferences when I click on file. I am trying to change the default image editor(pencyl) into GIMP. I have already downloaded Gimp but I don't know how to change the editor. Please give me a detailed step by step explanation, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Go to file>preferences.

On the top of the window, choose editors

Go to image editor and choose "choose application."

Find the directory for GIMP amd you're done!